# unsecapp connections

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm utilizing WMI on a remote machine using .NET's ManagementObject and similar classes.  Everything works great. But I have a concern about my app opening too many unsecapp connections every time form starts.  Connections are establish and not closed for a long time.
What this app approximately does is subscribes to some remote events with ManagementEventWatcher, calls Start on it (there are about 10-15 items of it).  Then on form close I call Stop on each of them and then Dispose.  Do you need some code or that is sufficient for your comments?